# Node.js/Express render view from client side with javascript

Tags: node.js, express, view, client-side, window.location

I am working on NodeJS/Express project. Running it on localhost I am trying to render a view on the client-side. But I get file not found error.
The javascript is located in /public/js folder. The view i am trying to render in views/view1.ejs

I tried

```
window.location('/view1')
window.location.replace('/view1')
```

Getting 404 error Not Found in either case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the url(route) instead of the path of the file. The window.location.replace takes a url(resource) as a parameter not a file. Declare this inside your index.js route file.

```
router.get("/view1",function(req,res,next){

    res.render("view1")

});
```

Comment: I was under impression it's possible to do it on a client side without routes. Trying to figure out the correct way to do it.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it if you are just using express js. Any resource that needs to be accessed from the server should be accessed through a route. Otherwise you'll get a 404. Think of it getting something from the server. You'll need to make a request which means a url . 

You can have a look at the  example as well https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace